# Insertar Datos Con PHP despues de tener tablas relacionadas en sql

Tags: php, base-de-datos, php5

Estoy haciendo una inserción de datos y entonces cree una tabla en la cual tengo dos tipos de usuario (administrador y cliente), pero cuando la relaciono con la tabla en la cual se van a almacenar todos los usuarios registrados, intento registrar un nuevo usuario y no me registra, ¿como podría solucionar esto con php? osea la parte en que al tener la relación en la BD no me esta registrando,

```
<code><?php
//Incluimos La Conexion
include ("conexion.php");

//Guardamos Valores En Variables
$nameuno = $_POST["nombreuno"];
$namedos = $_POST["nombredos"];
$lastuno = $_POST["apellidouno"];
$lastdos = $_POST["apellidodos"];
$tipoDoc = $_POST["Documento"];
$NroDoc = $_POST["Identificacion"];
$pass = $_POST["pass"];
$inst = $_POST["IU"];
$cargo = $_POST["cargo"];
$laboratorio = $_POST["laboratorio"];
$bloque = $_POST["bloque"];
$NroLabo = $_POST["NroLaboratorio"];

//Insertamos Los Datos Del Usuario En La BD
$insertar = "INSERT INTO `usuarios`( `NombreUno`, `NombreDos`, `ApellidoUno`, `ApellidoDos`, `TipoDocumento`, `NroDocumento`, `Contrasena`, `Institucion`, `Cargo`, `Laboratorio`, `Bloque`, `NroLaboratorio`) VALUES ('$nameuno', '$namedos', '$lastuno', '$lastdos', '$tipoDoc', '$NroDoc', '$pass', '$inst', '$cargo', '$laboratorio', '$bloque', '$NroLabo')";

//Verificacion De Documento
$verificar_documento = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE NroDocumento = '$NroDoc'");
if (mysqli_num_rows($verificar_documento) > 0){
    echo '<script>alert("El Usuario Ya Esta Registrado");
    window.history.go(-1);
    </script>';
    exit;
}

//Ejecutamos La Consulta
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $insertar);
if (!$resultado){
    echo '<script>alert("Error Al Registrar");
    window.history.go(-1);</script>';
    exit;
}else {
    echo '<script>alert("Usuario Registrado Exitosamente");
    window.history.go(-1);</script>';
    exit;
}

//Cerrar Sesion
mysqli_close($conexion);

?></code>
```

Comment: como podríamos solucionar que? amigo por favor lee [ask] y dedicale unos minutos a tu pregunta; si no muestras donde falla el código nosotros tampoco sabremos el por que

Answer (score 1):

Entiendo que lo que mencionas es que básicamente el código php que has puesto no te funciona bien y no se registran los usuarios.

No estoy seguro pero creo en esta línea puede haber un error con los apostrofes:

```
$insertar = "INSERT INTO `usuarios`( `NombreUno`, `NombreDos`, 
            `ApellidoUno`, `ApellidoDos`, `TipoDocumento`, `NroDocumento`, 
            `Contrasena`, `Institucion`, `Cargo`, `Laboratorio`, `Bloque`, 
            `NroLaboratorio`) VALUES ('$nameuno', '$namedos', '$lastuno', 
            '$lastdos', '$tipoDoc', '$NroDoc', '$pass', '$inst', '$cargo', 
            '$laboratorio', '$bloque', '$NroLabo')";
```

Cambia por esta y prueba:

```
$insertar = "INSERT INTO usuarios( NombreUno, NombreDos, ApellidoUno, 
            ApellidoDos, TipoDocumento, NroDocumento, Contrasena, 
            Institucion, Cargo, Laboratorio, Bloque, NroLaboratorio) VALUES 
            ('$nameuno', '$namedos', '$lastuno', '$lastdos', '$tipoDoc', 
             '$NroDoc', '$pass', '$inst', '$cargo', '$laboratorio', 
             '$bloque', '$NroLabo')";
```

Comment: el uso de las comillas **``** es perfectamente válido

Comment: En la base de datos sí que funciona, por ejemplo en phpmyadmin, pero en el propio php a mi en alguna ocasión me dió error dependiendo de la codificación creo, personalmente por eso ya nunca uso eso, que realmente no son comillas son los apóstrofos tipo acento que crea el gestor al copiar la consulta. No sé por probar.

Comment: no son un error y si funcionan, se ocupan cuando en la consulta se tratan columnas o tablas que tienen nombres propios del sistema, para diferenciarlas y que el gestor no interprete que invocas algun recurso propio de el